# I am currently doing BTech and have an average pointer. Is it possible for me to do my Master’s degree in an Top HCI University?

Tags: ux-field, hci, career-development, jobs, education

I am a 3rd yr Btech student from India.

Recently I confessed my love for UX and decided to pursue Master's in HCI or related field.

But I am currently in an average university and have an average pointer.

Is it possible for me to do my master’s in a top HCI university?

Please Guide me!

(Well its my first question on this website and if it is odd then sorry.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about UX.  It may be about education related to UX, but this would fall under the same category as asking for book suggestions, or where to apply for the best UX jobs (all of which are off-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. However, having prior work experience really helps especially if it's related to UX. I was in a similar situation to you, but because I had relevant work experience for 5 years, I was accepted to https://uclic.ucl.ac.uk which is regarded as one of the best HCI programs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any industry experience to fall back on? Even just a good head on your shoulders, a sense of empathy and human nature, and good communication skills? You might consider looking into the Bentley Masters of Human Factors and Interface Design program in Waltham, MA, USA.

http://www.bentley.edu/graduate/ms-programs/hfid

It is widely considered one of the best UX programs in the country, mostly for the strategy and research through information architecture, testing, collaboration, design management, prototyping phases of UX (not so much the visual design or coding aspects). All classes are also provided as hybrid local and remote classes, so students from all over the world attend both remotely and in person. They are also widely known as a business school, so they have that angle well covered.

Full disclosure: I went there, so yes, I'm a little biased! But not unreasonably so... it is a very fine program with some exceptional teachers (some less so, but that's like anywhere, I guess) and a great track record of turning out very fine UX professionals. As far as I can tell, they take the whole person into consideration more than specifically the grade point average or GRE scores - I know a few people who might have not been accepted based just on their numbers, but their experience, passion, story, all combined made them compelling enough for them to get in.

There is a lot that goes into being a good user experience professional, much of which does not come through in a GPA or test scores. The people who run that program - in particular professor Bill Gribbons, who is the head of the program - understand that, so it is absolutely worth reaching out to them and inquiring!

Answer (score 1):

User experience design is a very exciting filed of design . you dont need to be excelling in academics to get into design - but you should have eye for detailing and an ability to co-relate what you like and draw inspiration from that in your work.You have almost 2 years to prepare for the masters programme in India .

NID- B, Shristi School of Design (Bangalore) offers Design courses .
IIT Mumbai ( IDC) has interaction design at masters level - also at IITK,IITG,
Maeer's MIT institute of Design Pune offers User Experience Courses in Degree. Specific on UI/UX Interaction Design.
You also can learn on your own through online courses like Udemy / Lynda /or Coursera
For inperson training with shorter duration you have few 10 day modules offered by IDC or HFI

you can keep visiting my website where we post lot of things related to UX Umberlearningfacility .com